# How do I use cat to base64 encode stdin on the fly with openssl?

Tags: linux, command-line, openssl

The following command works for encoding `stdin` using `echo`:

```
echo "abc" | openssl enc -base64
```

This command also works for substituting characters in `stdin` using `cat`:

```
cat | sed 's/a/b/g'
```

However, the following command, which should encode `stdin` using `cat` does not meet my needs, because it doesn't display the encoded value every time I hit return.

```
cat | openssl enc -base64
```

How do I encode `stdin` on-the-fly using `cat`?

Comment: "Don't work" is not a very good problem description.

Answer (score 5):

If you type

```
cat | openssl enc -base64
```

and then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> then it will encode everything you just typed.

Comment: While that works, I need a continues result. IE I keep typing and every time I hit return, I get an encoded value out

Comment: @nick: If you want to get satisfactory answers, you should edit your question to add details like this.

Comment: @nick: to be clear, every time you press enter you want an encoded value just for that line of text, or for the entire body of text you've entered?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you (just about) ***never*** need to use `cat |` or `cat` *`one_file`* `|`. 
For example, your `sed` example works fine as

```
sed 's/a/b/g'
```

So my first suggestion is that you try

```
openssl enc -base64
```

without the `cat`.

But, honestly, I don’t expect that to work. You may need to get a little fancier:

```
while read x
do
      echo "$x" | openssl enc -base64
done
```

Note that this runs a new `openssl` command for each line of input, so this might not give the same results as the same input run through a single invocation of `openssl`.

Answer (score 0):

you can try with below command to convert it to Base64 encoding:

```
cat abc.jks | Base64
```

Comment: reread the question, they want to encode "stdin on the fly".